# Generator coils

Tags: electrical-engineering

If I am using a 9" long by 1" diameter coil for my generator, which way will be better to generate the most power? Slice the 9" coil into nine coils and connect them in series, or leave it as one coil?

Comment: Aren’t they already effectuvely in series when still in one piece?

Comment: Split and spread them over the circumference, the power remains the same, but you get smoother wave form, and as side effect, you get to damp the higher order harmonics.

Comment: What are your inductance, frequency R,L,f , I,V and B-H field specs?